# Visual Guideline for character per line limit

Tags: python, visual-studio-2017

Is there a sane way in Visual Studio 2017 to add a visual guideline in every Python project to not excceed the recommendet 79 characters per line limit by PEP 8?

Comment: You can use the options (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/formatting-python-code?view=vs-2017 under Wrapping)  to set the comment-length to 79, then format a long comment and add a guideline. Thats manual though, and does not keep between projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed [MS Productivity Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerPack2017) (free) which includes Guidelines. The homepage deprecates those and tells you to use [EditorGuidelines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PaulHarrington.EditorGuidelines) instead - I think I still have the original ones.

However:

Open a empty text editor, add 79 characters, rightlick, add Guideline and add it:

[image: Add Guideline]

Unfortunately this is language and project-agnostic. I am not using guidelines for anything else, so it works for me:

[image: my line]

Pro tip: to erase it, you need to move the cursor to its position (col 79) and can erase it via the right-click contextmenue.